# Get MAC address of all VMs from VMware

Tags: python, vmware, esx

I've a script that I've taken from the VMware documentation to get information of VMs through a python script and the API.

```
esummary = vm.summary
print("Name       : ", esummary.config.name)
print("IP         : ", esummary.guest.ipAddress)
```

Which gives me

```
VM1        : test-vm
IP         : 127.0.0.1
```

But I want to get a lot more information on each of the Vms. Specifically I'd like the interfaces and MAC address of each VM. Found a few links on how to do this via PowerShell but looking to do it via python instead if it's possible?

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi ?

Comment: @Rekovni have looked at pyvmomi but can't find MAC address anywhere in the returned dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out; found MAC addresses under

```
vm.config.hardware.device
```

so my code to print the MAC address is

```
hardware = vm.config.hardware.device
for d in hardware:
    if hasattr(d, 'macAddress'):
        print('MAC Address   : {}'.format(d.macAddress))
```